How to extract convert date in written text to numeric
I've a problem where I from a product description need to convert the months of the description to a billing period. Example description:
Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)
From this I would like to extract START_BILLING = 2024-06-01 and END_BILLING 2025-05-01, based on the fact that we start in June and end in may.
I can find the year of this from other items in the database but I don't know of any nice functions to do this easily.
Any suggestions? I work in snowflake
Been trying around with regexs and different string manipulators but haven't found a easy clean pick yet

How do you know if (MAY-JUNE) means May 2024 to June 2024, or to June 2025? And (JANUARY-FEBRUARY), is that January 2024 or 2025?

@jarlh The billing period is stated elsewhere in our database so I can get that information from there

So with the input data as you describe, you can ether REGEXP the two parts:
with data(description) as (
    select * from values
    ('Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)')
)
select 
    description,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',1) as start_s,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',2) as end_s
from data;


OR grap the whole bundle and string split on the -
Then decode the dates to dates. I am a little concerned your end month is the first day of the month not the last, but if we ignore that:
with data(description, year_from_elsewhere) as (
    select * from values
    ('Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)', 2024)
)
select 
    description,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',1) as start_s,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',2) as end_s,
    decode(start_s,
        'JANUARY', 1, 
        'MAY', 5, 
        'JUNE', 6 
        /* complete the 12 */
    ) as start_m,
    decode(end_s,
        'JANUARY', 1, 
        'MAY', 5, 
        'JUNE', 6 
        /* complete the 12 */
    ) as end_m,
    date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere, start_m, 1) as start_date,
    date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere+1, end_m, 1) as end_date
    
from data;

gives:

This has a hack assuming end is in the next year, which is incorrect for JAN-DEC
another alternative if END is always 11 months after the start:
dateadd('month', 11, start_date) as end_alternate

OR if you want correct
    date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere+iff(end_m < start_m, 1, 0), end_m, 1) as correct_end_date,

with data(description, year_from_elsewhere) as (
    select * from values
    ('Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)', 2024),
    ('blar blar (JANUARY-DEC)', 2024),
    ('more blar (JUNE-SEP)', 2024)
)
select 
    description,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',1) as start_s,
    regexp_substr(description,'\\(([A-Z]+)-([A-Z]+)\\)',1,1,'ce',2) as end_s,
    decode(start_s,
        'JANUARY', 1, 
        'MAY', 5, 
        'JUNE', 6,
        'SEP', 9,
        'DEC', 12
        /* complete the 12 */
    ) as start_m,
    decode(end_s,
        'JANUARY', 1, 
        'MAY', 5, 
        'JUNE', 6,
        'SEP', 9,
        'DEC', 12
        /* complete the 12 */
    ) as end_m,
    date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere, start_m, 1) as start_date,
    --date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere+1, end_m, 1) as bad_end_date,
    --dateadd('month', 11, start_date) as end_alternate,
    date_from_parts(year_from_elsewhere+iff(end_m < start_m, 1, 0), end_m, 1) as correct_end_date,
from data;



Thank you, I decided to use this solution and continued refining the regex pattern to handle all edge-cases.

If you don't want to do decoding, case statements, or Regex, then I would just use a split_part for your text string and then format that into a TO_DATE function.
Using your example and assuming you're getting dates from elsewhere, this works perfectly fine with A LOT less coding:
with x as (SELECT '(JUNE-MAY)' as val)
SELECT TRIM(TRIM(val,'('),')') as trimmed_val,
       LEFT(SPLIT_PART(trimmed_val,'-',1),3) as first_month,
       LEFT(SPLIT_PART(trimmed_val,'-',2),3) as second_month,
       '2024' as first_year,
       '2025' as second_year,
       TO_DATE(first_month||first_year,'MONYYYY') as first_date,
       TO_DATE(second_month||second_year,'MONYYYY') as second_date
from x;

Note: it's even less coding, but I broke it down into separate columns along the way so you could easily see the logic, but all of that could be consolidated into single lines of code.

smirk, using the to_date, with the string input, that is a chunk of less work than DECODE, good call.

@SimeonPilgrim you still got the accepted answer, though. :shrug:

I think they liked my REGEXP, I assume that part was more messy, but your string (as presented) to date was cleaner. I gave you a up vote.

If I understood well the following input :

Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)

the output should be :
description                                                         start_year  start_month end_month   START_BILLING   END_BILLING
Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)   2024        06          05          2024-06-0       2025-05-01

you may need to use mainly SPLIT_PART with REGEXP_SUBSTR:
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Transaction packages 2500 transactions / year included (JUNE-MAY)' AS description,
         2024 AS start_year 
)

SELECT 
    description,
    start_year,

    -- Here you extract billing period from the description 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)') AS billing_period,

    -- then the start month and convert it to a numeric value
    CASE 
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'JANUARY' THEN '01'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'FEBRUARY' THEN '02'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'MARCH' THEN '03'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'APRIL' THEN '04'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'MAY' THEN '05'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'JUNE' THEN '06'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'JULY' THEN '07'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'AUGUST' THEN '08'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'SEPTEMBER' THEN '09'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'OCTOBER' THEN '10'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'NOVEMBER' THEN '11'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'DECEMBER' THEN '12'
    END AS start_month,

    -- Here you can extract the end month and convert it also to a numeric value
    CASE 
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'JANUARY' THEN '01'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'FEBRUARY' THEN '02'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'MARCH' THEN '03'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'APRIL' THEN '04'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'MAY' THEN '05'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'JUNE' THEN '06'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'JULY' THEN '07'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'AUGUST' THEN '08'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'SEPTEMBER' THEN '09'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'OCTOBER' THEN '10'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'NOVEMBER' THEN '11'
        WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'DECEMBER' THEN '12'
    END AS end_month,

    TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(start_year) || '-' || 
            CASE 
                WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 1) = 'JUNE' THEN '06'
            END || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS START_BILLING,

    -- Here I added the year + 1 if it's a year rollover
    TO_DATE(TO_VARCHAR(start_year + 1) || '-' || 
            CASE 
                WHEN SPLIT_PART(REGEXP_SUBSTR(description, '\\(([^\\)]+)\\)'), '-', 2) = 'MAY' THEN '05'
            END || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS END_BILLING

FROM data


You can help us by upvoting the answer or leaving a feedback if the solution fits your expectations :)
